# Combine form values under one name using GET method

Tags: php, forms, foreach, get, getmethod

I have a form using the GET method consisting of checkboxes.

This form is sending data to another page that is receiving the GET info and using it to pull info from a json api.  I need to have it send the name once with all values combined into one string like this: example.com/color=RedGreenBlue

I am able to get all values combined and echoed onto the page but because they are in a foreach loop I am not able to pass them in the form.  I tried below using the hidden field to pass them with no luck.

This is the method I've seen suggested but does not work for me:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    Red<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red">
    Green<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green">
    Blue<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

<?php
$name = $_GET['color'];
if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
        foreach ($name as $color){
            echo $color;
    }
} 
?>
<input type="hidden" name="MajorArea" value="<?php echo $color; ?>" /> 
</form>
```

Is there a way to assign one name to a group of checkboxes?  Is there a way to pull the foreach loop data and use it outside a loop?  Am I overlooking a way that is much easier than this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Using your existing form, just do this on the receiving page `$color = implode($_GET['color']);`

Comment: Why won't this method work for you? Maybe it would be better to modify the backend code than a "normal behaviour" of form & GET query string?

Comment: It really makes no sense why you'd do this. The checkbox is either `checked` or it's not. If the value is present in the `$_GET['color']` array then the checkbox was `checked` i.e. the inverse logic is to `echo checked` inside the `<input>` tag while traversing the array. Othersise, trying to use `$_GET` to capture the input before the from has even been submitted would be futile. You'd have to do that with JS on the front end.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I get warnings that implode is not an array.
I might be making this too complex...I just need to send one name with combined values using the GET method.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb here and delete if it isn't what you're after.  `$_GET['color']` will be an array or it will be empty.  You could also use `isset`:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    Red<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red">
    Green<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green">
    Blue<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_GET['color'])) {
    echo implode($_GET['color']);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This definitely displays all the values but I still can't seem to get this info in the URL so the Get method can work.

Comment: @JoeyLawrence what URL are you talking about? The one your form submits to? The one your are making the API request to, separately?